# geogebra: create 3d spline

Tags: geometry, surfaces, mathematical-modeling, math-software

I want to create a 3-D spline, so that it's like a smooth surface in geogebra. I tried using the spline command, which takes a list of point and even though there are different Z values, that is still generating a 2-D spline. What am I missing here ?

[image: geogebra schreenshot with a 2D spline in a 3D space]

I create another tuple inside so now I can use both in case two tuples are required however would be mainly interested in creating a spline so that the enclosed area is completely opaque

[now with another tuple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJ4me.png)

Comment: is geogebra, algebraic -geometry ?

Comment: geogebra is a software. sorry I was looking for a tag but couldn't find. and also other questions do not have geogebra tag

Comment: added math software tag.

Comment: ok thank you. you wouldn't happen to know the answer by any chance?

Comment: Why don't you just try reading the [manual](https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/Manual), instead of making others do that for you?

Comment: thanks professor vector can you point where exactly in the documentation you found it? I did try looking thoroughly through the help pages and google the closest thing I found was making a tube to repeat the spline https://www.geogebra.org/m/QnxvNDt2. I need only one side to be created

Comment: I'm a PARI/GP person and not a very good one ( don't know half the commands as they are too deep in number theory).

Comment: ok thank you for your help Roddy with formatting maybe the Professor can help he said he found it in the manual

Comment: might be that you need 2 sets of 3 tuples that are separated by distance ...  to make something with thickness. @Rott he linked to it so he didn't have to do any more help.